# Is it possible to put the XML content in a field of the database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I was analyzing my situation and I face with the problem that I need to save the content of an XML file in SQL SERVER 2008. My XML files have a size around 200KB to 600KB

For the momment, how would I define the field to accept this content? I can imagine I can set the content directly but I'm not sue about this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was watching that the Datatype list contains XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL 2008 supports a dedicated `xml` data type, which is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187339.aspx).

Some details include the following for fragments, and documents, respectively:

> Restricts the xml instance to be a well-formed XML fragment. The XML
> data can contain multiple zero or more elements at the top level. Text
> nodes are also allowed at the top level.
>
> Restricts the xml instance to be a well-formed XML document. The XML
> data must have one and only one root element. Text nodes are not
> allowed at the top level.

Also, a point on capacity (though a 2GB limitation should be hard to reach in the majority of cases):

> The stored representation of xml data type instances cannot exceed 2
> gigabytes (GB) in size. For more information, see [Implementing XML in
> SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189887.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server has a datatype called XML. Use that.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server has an `xml` [data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187339.aspx) exactly for that purpose.  For example:

```
create table YourTable (id int identity, FileContent xml)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with SQL Server 2005+ you can use the `xml` data type. You'll need to be sure that your data is actually well-formed XML, though. If it's just snippets you're better off using `nvarchar`.

File sizes of 200 - 600 KB are no issue for the `xml` column type.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using BLOB data types or CLOB ?

Answer (score 0):

SQLServer has an XML datatype.. have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can store XML text in a text field in your SQL database, but if you're planning to do a lot of introspection on that XML data, you'll probably be better off using MS-SQL's XML data type.  This stores the XML data in tokenized form on the server and makes it possible to perform XML query operations without having to reparse the XML data all the time.  I seem to recall you can also index on XML expressions as well.